# Xamarin - Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, twilio, linker-errors

I have a Xamarin Forms iOS project which is failing to build with this error

```
Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: TCDeviceDelegate. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_TCDeviceDelegate' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.
```

It starts the build and fails with this error after about 10 minutes (older model MacBook so its slow).

This TCDeviceDelegate class is part of the nuget.org package - Twilio.Client.Component v1.0.1
Which results in the following DLL being included in the iOS project - TwilioClient.iOS-Unified.dll

My PC environment is:

- Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.7.4
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02556
- Xamarin 4.10.10.2 (35a01d8dc)
- Xamarin Designer 4.12.1 (f3257e429)
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 11.12.0.4 (64fece5)

On my MacBook it is paired fine, also running the latest Visual Studio:

- Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac (v.7.5.3)
- Xamarin.iOS v.11.12.04

What I have tried:

- Removing and adding the Twilio NuGet package
- Rebooting PC and Mac
- Removing bin/obj folders and rebuild
- Clean and rebuild every time
- Removing the packages folder Twilio DLLs
- Tried setting the linker behaviour to both "Link Framework SDKs Only" and also "Link All"

All of the above had no effect, the build fails with the same error every time

Any help would be greatly appreciated

This error only started happening after upgrading to VS 7.5.3 on Mac along with Xamarin.iOS v.11.12.04.

Comment: At this point we are going to be forced to remove the Twilio VoiP functionality from our app to get it to build, which is obviously not ideal.

Comment: Since we integrated Twilio, the Twilio Client iOS / Android SDKs have been deprecated and replaced by Twilio Programmable Voice SDK. So we're currently using deprecated SDKs and so suspect we'll have issues getting assistance to make the nuget package support Xamarin.iOS 11.12.0.4.